# Session object's autowired properties do not autowire if the session object is declared <aop:scoped-proxy>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Session object's autowired properties do not autowire if the session object is declared

```
<bean id="user" class="org.User" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

The user objects proerty is @autowired but the property doesn't get autowired.

```
public class User 
{
    TemplateService templateService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTemplateService(TemplateService templateService) {
        this.templateService = templateService;
    }
}
```

I wonder why this is so.
Is replacing the autowire annotations with xml declarations the only solution. Are there any other solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please also show how you are getting a reference to user in your code, if it is through Spring then yes the templateService should have been injected, if it is somehow outside then no it will not be injected.